# How do I fix mystery package dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 on a new laptop, and the garbage OS has already botched itself up.

The basic problem is that I cannot `apt-get install` any package that depends on `gcc-7-base` or `gcc-8-base`.  For example,

```
libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
libgfortran4 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
```

According to `apt-cache policy`, these are the current versions of `gcc-7-base` or `gcc-8-base`:

```
$ apt-cache policy gcc-7-base
gcc-7-base:
  Installed: 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Candidate: 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
$ apt-cache policy gcc-8-base
gcc-8-base:
  Installed: 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Candidate: 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8-20180414-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

The installed versions have different names than the versions in the repo; the versions in the repo have the name that the other packages seem to expect.

`$ apt-cache showpkg gcc-7-base` shows that both versions have the exact same "File" origin and MD5 hash:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg gcc-7-base
Package: gcc-7-base
Versions: 
7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: b6e93638a6d08ea7a18929d7cf078e5d
...
7.3.0-16ubuntu3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: b6e93638a6d08ea7a18929d7cf078e5d
```

(with a similar result for `gcc-8-base`, I'll post it if anyone asks).  So as far as I can tell the 'bad' (installed) packages are the exact same packages as the 
'good' (expected) packages, and from the same source, but for some reason they have different names, and that's preventing things like `libquadmath0` and `libgfortran4` from installing.

A web search for "7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04" gives this [description page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/gcc-7) for the bionic-updates repo as the only relevant hit, but the only "updates" repos in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` are commented out, and I've never knowingly had them enabled.

So, my first question is
**1)** How did the packages `7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04` and `8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04` get installed on my computer?  Is there any way of knowing this?

My second question is
**2)** How do I fix it using `apt-get`?  Since the highest-priority versions of each in the output of `apt-cache policy` are the "correct" versions, would

```
$ apt-get remove gcc-7-base
$ apt-get install gcc-7-base
```

produce the correct configuration of having `7.3.0-16ubuntu3` and `8-20180414-1ubuntu2` installed for the packages `gcc-7-base` and `gcc-8-base`, respectively?

For the record, I've tried an update/upgrade/autoremove cycle, I've tried `apt-get install -f`, and I've tried `apt-get clean`. None of these had any effect whatsoever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve package conflicts between Ubuntu and GIMP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097914/how-do-i-resolve-package-conflicts-between-ubuntu-and-gimp)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:
versions you're asking about seem to be the default package versions for 18.04 (this is my output):

`jan@jan-XPS-9550:~$ sudo apt-get install libquadmath0 libgfortran4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
libgfortran4 is already the newest version (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04).
libquadmath0 is already the newest version (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04).`

Answer to question 2:
I think your best bet would be to:

`apt-get remove --purge libgfortran4 libquadmath0 gcc-7-base  gcc-8-base
apt-get autoremove
reboot (just in case, most likely not needed at all)
install packages again`

then it should go back to default / non-conflicting ones